# Creating a module on JS that have to get data from a RESTFUL API

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise

Hi I was creating a JS module that I want to use in the way:

```
var dataCollection = new dataCollectionSetup();
var collectedData = dataCollection.getMeasures(2);
```

My issue is that I want to get data from a Restfull Api and that will be asynchronously. I create this module but I am stuck on how create the promise inside the function or something that allow me call the `getMeausre` in the way that I showed or like this  `dataCollection.getMeasures(2).then(UpdatecoolectedData(res)).`

```
var dataCollectionSetup = function () {

    var getMeasuresByTrainingDomainId = function (tdId)
    {
        var jsonResponse;

        fnSuccess = function (data, status, request) {

            jsonResponse = data;
            return jsonResponse
        };

        fnError = function () {
            alert("Error getting Maasures by Training Domain");
        }

        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "/datacollection/Measures/" + timelineId,
            complete: fnSuccess,
            error: fnError
        });
    }

    var getMetrics = function () {
        var result = CallApiForMetrics()
        return result;
    }



    return {
        getMeasures: getMeasuresByTrainingDomainId,
        getNetric: getMetrics
    }
}
```

Thank you

Comment: If you return the 'result' of the Ajax call (not the callback) you will have a promise that contains a 'then' method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just make the following change to your function **getMeasuresByTrainingDomainId**

```
return  $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "/datacollection/Measures/" + timelineId,
        complete: fnSuccess,
        error: fnError
    });
```

If you look [the jquery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) for the ajax method, implement the Promise interface, and you can use it like this:

```
var dataCollection = dataCollectionSetup();
dataCollection.getMeasures(2).then(function(){/*your coode*/})
```